# Can't find entry point

Tags: c++, program-entry-point, visual-studio-2019, entry-point

I wanted to create an new c++ project and start coding. I am working in an existing solution with 30+ projects in it. So instead of main() GwMain(..) is used. This works for all other files but not when I create a new c++ project. I get a linker error:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int__cdel invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)

File: MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj)
```

- I already compared the property configs with the other projects and
  it is nearly the same. The solution is migrated from visual studio
  2012 to 2019 I guess this is one of the reasons why it is not working
  how it should.
- I checked already this: Linker->System->SubSystem -> Windows.

  And when I change it from console to windows it shows this:

  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _WinMain referenced in function
  "int__cdel invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
- And I do not use cmake
- When I use int main(){return 0;} I get no errors, but I have to use
  GwMain()
- When I change Under Advanced the EntryPoint I actually get more
  errors. I tried to insert GwMain.

The code is just like this:

```
#include <gwcore.hpp>
#include <gw.hpp>

int GwMain(int, char**)
{

    return 0;
}
```

Grit is used here a very old framework.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I'm fairly sure the problem is that you're not linking correctly with whatever GW library this is intended to work with. I have no idea what that is, but the `GwMain` will be called from the library `main` function (presumably surrounded by some initialization and/or tear-down code that needs to run before / after `GwMain`. I'm not familiar with this, and haven't written code for Windows for years now.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Project > Properties > General > Project Defaults > Configuration Type.

If this is ".exe" then a main is needed for this project. Else if this is ".dll" or ".lib" your code should compile.

Comment: The config type is Application (.exe). But I have here multiple projects that also use GwMain instead of main as the entry point and are also .exe.

Comment: @S.Yildiz Look at those other exe-projects what libraries they link to. The required main function will be provided by one of these libraries then and you haven't linked against that one yet.

Answer (score 0):

After checking all the compilation and linking options with other projects that work fine.

From your solution, select a project that works (and that uses GwMain). Right button-> property and check its dependencies in "common properties":

[image]

Do this manipulation on the other projects that work correctly (and that use GwMain) and try to see if there is a **common dependency** which allows them to use GwMain, then, try to add this dependency to your project that does not work